# SharePoint 2010: Register InfoPath forms and use custom feature reciver jointly

Tags: infopath, feature-receiver

I am new to SharePoint, sorry if answer to my question is obvious.
I am using Custom InfoPath Task Forms in my project. For form registering, I am using next code in Feature.Template.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"
     Title="Prepare workflows"       
     ReceiverClass="Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Feature.WorkflowFeatureReceiver"
     ReceiverAssembly="Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Feature, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">
   <Properties>
       <Property Key="GloballyAvailable" Value="true" />
       <Property Key="RegisterForms" Value="Forms\*.xsn"/>
   </Properties>
 </Feature>
```

Also I want to use my custom FeatureReceiver (for workflow associating). But I don't know, how can I use it both (it works perfectly separately). Is any way to do it (may be, call to registration method of Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Feature.WorkflowFeatureReceiver in FeatureInstalled in my receiver?

I can try to do registration of my forms whole from the code in my feature receiver, but I think, may be there is a different, more elegant approach?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you not consider to create two features? One with `WorkflowFeatureReceiver` and another with your custom receiver.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I thought about it, but I think it is more like work-around than solution. I guess, there should be more elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can inherit your receiver from `WorkflowFeatureReceiver` (because it is public class) and then override FeatureActivated\FeatureDeactivating methods with your own logic. And also remove call to `base.FeatureActivated` if it is not desired.